# Downgrade without SHSH2 Blobs

Tags: ios, icloud, jailbreak

I recently upgraded to iOS 12.0 from 11.2 and I didn't save my SHSH2 blobs. In the process, I stupidly lost my jailbreak and realized there are no iOS 12 jailbreaks that are public yet. How do you downgrade to iOS 11.2 without SHSH2 blobs? I am aware that downgrading results in a factory reset and restoring your data with iCloud will bring it up to that iOS version, unless there is a way to do it that I am not aware of...

Answer (score 2):

You don't - without SHSH2 blobs you won't be able to.